# Laravel access controllers using different routes depending on user group

Tags: laravel-5

I currently have a `booker` and `admin` user groups.  A `booker` user is assigned to 1 `event`, and an `admin` user is not assigned to any event.

Both user groups have route groups like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'booker'], function() {

    Route::controller('event', 'EventController');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {

    Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');

});
```

Actions in `EventController` are like this:

```
getIndex      /event
getOverview   /event/overview
postOverview  /event/overview
getFacilities /event/facilities
postFacilties /event/facilities
etc.
```

When logged in as `admin` user group, is it possible for me to use the `EventController` actions for routes like this:

```
/admin/events/1
/admin/events/1/overview
/admin/events/1/facilties
/admin/events/1/schedule
etc.
```

Where, instead of getting the `event` id from the user, I would get it from the URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get there, although it's quite messy so I'd still love to know if there is a nicer solution:

routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'booker'], function() {

    Route::controller('event', 'EventController');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {

    Route::controller('admin/events/{id?}', 'EventController');
    Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
    Route::get('event', function() { return redirect('admin'); });

});
```

In EventController (using Sentry):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $user = Sentry::getUser();

    if($user->hasAccess('admin')) {
        $id = Request::segment(3);
        $event = Event::find($id);
        if(!$event) {
            abort(404);
        }
    } else {
        $event = $user->event;
    }

    $this->data['event'] = $event;
}
public function getIndex()
{    
    return view('event.index', $this->data);
}
```

So as you can see I've had to use the URL segment for the id, as I couldn't find a way to pass the id variable in the route.  The route variable just enables me to ignore the id and load the controller.

I found I couldn't use URLs like this within EventController views:

```
<a href="{{ URL::action('EventController@getOverview') }}">Overview<a>
// /event/overview
// /admin/events//overview
```

However using other helpers I could hack it in:

```
<a href="{{ URL::full().'/overview' }}">Overview<a>
// /event/overview
// /admin/events/3/overview
```